# Problems getting openlayers permalink working

Tags: openlayers-2

I set up an openlayers permalink function. I set the code and it shows up. But the URL does not work. Where is 
I get a link like this: 
http://babkart.no/?zoom=9&lat=7016094.01622&lon=121216.28057&layers=BFFFTTTTTF

The only thing that works is the chosen layers. It does not show the correct zoom or boundingbox. What do I need in the code to get this to work? I can not see I have any variables like "lat", "lon" or "zoom". Any examples as how to get this to work? I also would like to put the permalink in the toolbar so that one can copy the URL. I am using ExtJS 2.2.
But this is another issue and I have to get the permalink to work first.

I add the permalink like this:

```
controls: [new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults(),new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),new OpenLayers.Control.Permalink()]
```

My app.js is here if anyone wants to take a look:
http://pastebin.com/AstbpBWV
The site is running here: http://babkart.no/

~asle

I got this to work this way. Don't know if it was good or bad but it seems to work:
I use a function to zoom in to a location and added functionality to just zoom in to the view. I use the OpenLayers.Permalink() function.

```
        // If URL contains ref. to a location:
        var args = OpenLayers.Util.getParameters();
        if (args.x && args.y) {
            var position = new OpenLayers.LonLat(parseFloat(args.x), parseFloat(args.y));
            map.setCenter(position, 14);
            var xy = map.getViewPortPxFromLonLat(position);
            xy.x = Math.round(xy.x);
            xy.y = Math.round(xy.y);
            info.getInfoForClick({xy: xy});
        } // read the permalink URL
        else if (args.lat && args.lon && args.zoom) {
            var position = new OpenLayers.LonLat(parseFloat(args.lon), parseFloat(args.lat));
            map.setCenter(position, parseFloat(args.zoom));
        }
        else {
                map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(528277, 7188837), 3);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you use GeoExt. There is own permalink mechanism for using within GeoExt. See [docs](http://www.geoext.org/lib/GeoExt/state/PermalinkProvider.html) and [example](http://api.geoext.org/1.1/examples/permalink.html).

Comment: Thanks. I am using Mapfish and Extjs and there are GeoExt components but when I use the GeoExt sample I get errors. Sorry I did not make this solution all by myself so I am a bit confused. When I use the code from the GeoExt docs or example I get error. It does not understand:

var permalinkProvider = new GeoExt.state.PermalinkProvider();

Where do I start to look? It seems that the OpenLayers.permalink is accepted but it does not understand the params for zoom,lat,lon.

Comment: I see the code in the javascript for "Ext.extend(Ext.state.CookieProvider,Ext.state.Provider....." so it seems I could use that but maybe where exactly to put it in my app.js is the problem?