# OpenLayers/Extjs/Mapfish put permaink in menubar

Tags: openlayers-2, ext-js, mapfish

I solved my problem [Problems getting openlayers permalink working](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/25947/7367) on how to get the maps view permalink but now I want to put the permalink in the toolbar instead of reloading the page with the permalink. I would like a popup like the one here on stackexchange when you click the "Link" under the post. That pops up a box with the URL selected.

Here is my map: http://babkart.no/ and the toolbar is like this now:

```
var setToolbarContent = function() {

toolbar.addControl(
        new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomToMaxExtent({
            map: map,
            title: 'Zoom til kartets maksimumsvisning'
        }), {
    iconCls: 'zoomfull',
    toggleGroup: 'map'
}
        );

addSeparator();

toolbar.addControl(
        new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomBox({
            title: 'Zoom inn: klikk i kartet eller bruk venstre museknapp for å tegne en rektangel'
        }), {
    iconCls: 'zoomin',
    toggleGroup: 'map'
}
        );
toolbar.addControl(
        new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomBox({
            out: true,
            title: 'Zoom ut: klikk i kartet eller bruk venstre museknapp for å tegne en rektangel'
        }), {
    iconCls: 'zoomout',
    toggleGroup: 'map'
}
        );
toolbar.addControl(
        new OpenLayers.Control.DragPan({
            isDefault: true,
            title: 'Pan kartet: hold venstre museknapp inne og dra i kartet'
        }), {
    iconCls: 'pan',
    toggleGroup: 'map'
}
        );
toolbar.addControl(
        new OpenLayers.Control.DragPan({
            title: 'Vis info: klikk på et ikon for å vise mere informasjon'
        }), {
    iconCls: 'info',
    toggleGroup: 'map'
}
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know whether this works for you or not, but you can try something to add permalink info to a button tooltip as another DragPan. in the following code you should change iconcls and togglegroup for new button...

```
     toolbar.addControl(
     var con = map.controls;
     var permalinkInfo;

     for(var a = 0; a< con.length; a++){
        if(con[a].CLASS_NAME == "OpenLayers.Control.Permalink"){
            permalinkInfo = con[a].base
           }
         }

    new OpenLayers.Control.DragPan({
    title: permalinkInfo
    }), {
    iconCls: 'permalink',
    toggleGroup: 'other'
     }
    );
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Thanks but I get this error:

Syntax error
var con = map.controls;

Comment: What I would really like is to use an Ext messagebox like the "prompt" example her:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/message-box/msg-box.html

But I am using ExtJS 2.2. If I could open a box like the the div that opens when you click on "link" under a message here on the forum that would be nice.